# An array declared ouside the method(at class level), and assgned values inside a method doesn't work. Why?

Tags: java

**I made an array.. at the class level,but assigned it's values inside a method.. but for some reason.. it gave up an error..
 then when i did the array declaration & assignment inside of the same method..
 everything functioned smoothly!! Why is that? I declared the array at class level.. so it has class scope right?? so why can't i assign it values inside a method?? I'm utterly confused :/ **

```
public class VacationScale{



public int [] days;

days = new int [7];


public void setVacationScale(){

    days[0]=10;
days[1]=15;
days[2]=15;
days[3]=15;
days[4]=20;
days[5]=20;
days[6]=25;

}

public void displayVacationDays(int yearsOfService){
    if(yearsOfService >=0 && yearsOfService<=6){
    System.out.println("the years of the service of the employee is "
        +yearsOfService+ " and hence the employee is eligible to :" 
        +days[yearsOfService]+ " holidays"); 
    }
    else if(yearsOfService >6){

        System.out.println("the years of the service of the employee is "
            +yearsOfService+ " and hence the employee is eligible to :25" 
        +" holidays"); 


    }
    else{
    System.out.println("invalid number of years of service");

    }

}
```

}

*The error that shows up on the command prompt is--*  `identifier expected`

Comment: For God's sake! Format your code snippets before posting them! Virtually All IDEs can format your source codes just by clicking a menu item or something! Besides, is this the working code or the one that's not working?

Comment: if you want days to remain global then just do this - `public int [] days = new int [7];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `days = new int [7];` is invalid code outside of a method. Instead write:

```
public int [] days = new int [7];
```

which will both declare and initialize the array.

Beyond this, there is no need for your `setVacationScale()` method, since it appears to be hardcoded. Instead, you can initialize the array to have these values:

```
public int [] days = new int[] {10, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 25};
```

To give a few more tips, it's unwise to expose access to the array outside the class if it's only used by the class's methods - if this is the case change its access modifier to `private`. And as long as the array is only initialized once, it's good form to make it `final`:

```
private final int [] days = new int[] {10, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 25};
```

Comment: Why is it invalid outside a method? Do you mean that i will always have to declare the size of the array and then assign it's values inside the same method?? :/

Comment: @Iam - Greg seems to have explained this - let me know if you still need help.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is not valid to put in the class declaration:

```
days = new int[7];
```

Change it to an inline initialization:

```
public int[] days = new int[7];
```

Or put it in an initialization block:

```
{
    days = new int[7];
}
```

Or move it into the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class VacationScale{

    public int [] days;

    days = new int [7];
```

That snippet appears to be causing your problem. You cannot assign a new value to `days` outside a method.

Perhaps you could try assigning it at the start of `setVacationScale()`:

```
public void setVacationScale() {
    days = new int [7];
    days[0]=10;
    // ...
```

Comment: It's the rules of Java. An assignment is a *statement*, and a statement runs as part of a *method*. A statement outside a method doesn't make sense to the compiler.

Comment: Why is it invalid outside a method? Do you mean that i will always have to declare the size of the array and then assign it's values inside the same method?? :/

Comment: No, **statements** are invalid outside a method. However, there are many other ways to declare the size of an array and assign its values, as the other answers to this question show.

Comment: Thanks Greg ... got the Logic ;)